# Create a database in only one shard

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo, it's possible to have a database residing in only one server (but without sharding)?

- I'd like to use Mongo to store our **application logs**, but I'd like to have them on a different machine than the rest of the data.
- In this way if we start to send too many log messages, only the machine with the logging database will be slowed down.
- Ideally it should be transparent to the application, and which-machine-has-which-database should be managed by the MongoS process.

*Nb: We don't want to shard our entire database yet, since we are ok with the performances at this point, we'd like only to isolate the db with the logging collections.*

Comment: Nonsense question since you can of course run MongoDB without sharding and without replica sets as standalone server. What's your point?

Comment: I want to separate the application database from the logging database.
Also I want this to be managed by MongoS.

Comment: I agree with @ich. if you want to separate the app database from the logging database, just use two single mongod instances and two databases

Comment: But then I'd have that logic in the application, can't this be managed by the mongos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use 2 mongoD with 2 different servers, one with your actual database and one with the logging database.

The trick is to shard each of the db, but **none** of the collections.

Then with the movePrimary command you can choose where those unsharded collections will be actually stored.

(see: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/movePrimary+Command)

In your case, you'll do:

```
db.adminCommand({movePrimary:applicationdb, to:application_shard})
db.adminCommand({movePrimary:loggingdb, to:logging_shard})
```

However notice that when you'll decide to shard your applicationdb, mongo will automatically start to propagate your data also to the loggingdb_shard

Comment: It's stated in the docs, but it probably should be noted here that moving the primary requires a restart or 'flushRouterConfig' command of all mongos instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run a mongos on your application server and run a mongod process on another machine to store your logs. 
But if you want to use mongos you have to use sharding - but you can use a single shard. 
You will need to run the mongod process as --shardsvr and add this single shard to the mongos process. You will also need to run at least 1 config server. 
With this setup there are data redundancy issues - so you might want to run more than on mongod process - use a replica set within your single shard and run those mongod processes on different machines. And if you were going to do that you could also run 3 config servers (it's a choice of 1 or 3 with sharding set up) - 2 on 1 node of the replica set and 1 on the other.
Also for logging people often use capped collections.

Comment: Thanks,
the data redundancy issues are the same of a single-server with journaling? 
Or There are some specific issues for this case?

(since this is a non-vital part, we can deal with some data losses)

Comment: Journaling will give you data consistency in the event of power loss to the machine. But if the machine/disk fails completely then you will have lost your entire dataset unless you are using replication. It depends on how important your logs are whether you would want to use it or not. There's nothing specific for this case no.